# Lock for extremely frequent use

Tags: parts, security, lock, urban-riding, theft

Are there lock products out there specifically designed for easy handling when locked unlocked dozens of times a day?

I'm using a normal, chain-based lock at the moment and I'm annoyed because

- I'm doing constant slight damage to the frame when removing the lock from the bicycle
- I need to carry a key at all times, fumble it from my pocket when it's time to go (often in a thankless, noisy, roadside environment), and fumble the lock back onto the bicycle

Are there any solutions out there that make frequent use as painless, and still as secure, as possible? I'm thinking about something that works like a remote-controlled car door lock. It should, however, still be possible to attach the bike to an object to prevent it from getting carried away.

> Related: [best bike lock](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/141/best-bike-lock)

Comment: From the type of lock you're currently using, are you locking your bike up in a city?

Comment: @neilfein yes, exactly.

Answer (score 10):

For frequent use, I think it is hard to beat a lock that is built into the bike, e.g. the [Axa Defender](http://austinontwowheels.org/2008/08/06/review-axa-defender-rear-wheel-lock/) that is fixed to the fame of the bike and then locks the wheel; it also has a cable that you can use to lock the bike to the bake stand.  It’s great for a lock on a “everyday” bike, as you can’t forget to take it with you.

[image: Image of bike lock]
[image]

Comment: Yes, these are the best. Quick locking without cable hassle if you're just parking for a short while, with the possibility to attach your bike to something if need be. Also, very difficult to break open.

Answer (score 10):

A trick that couriers use around my area is to carry the key on a rubber band around their wrist - no more fumbling around in the pockets for a key. I find that a lock that you can wear across your chest like a bandolier is most convenient for carrying around. There are a number of chain locks around in this length that have a plastic tube over the chain to prevent scratches.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend kryptonite. The Evolution Mini is used by a number of my friends (messengers) and they use it many times in a day. Keeps things secure and it's small. If you want a bit more flexibility in what you can attach to then go for a larger sized one.

https://www.kryptonitelock.com/products/list.aspx?cid=1001&scid=1000

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to *part* of your question -- that of scratching up your bike while removing the chain: I used to have a chain lock with a plastic sleeve, to prevent just this. You could probably find a similar sleeve in any hardware store, just use some inexpensive transparent tubing.

Comment: Or, if you don't have any inexpensive transparent tubing, use an old inner tube! (Uses for old inner tube no. 40923.)

Answer (score 4):

After working as a Courier in Toronto for a few years (and some other cities), I have found that the best lock (in my experience) has been something of good heft and quality from Master Lock & a length of thick chain from the hardware long enough to wrap around your waist while ridding. (they make some nice steal & brass ones with combinations insted of keys if your not to keen on a key with the jonas of being pretty corrosion/oxidation resistant).

If its long enough to wrap around your waist like a belt, its usually long enough to loop around your frame, wheel set, and something sturdy to anchor on.

Your bike won't be going anywhere & it will only set you back about $15

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Falling on a chain will be unpleasant to say the least