# Commuting daily with an Expensive Bike, tips?

Tags: commuter, lock, security, parking

I have been commuting to work daily for years now. Sadly I just switched jobs and there is no bike parking, so I have to leave it in the street. My main problem is that I'm riding a Colnago Single Speed, so I'm not a fan of that solution in the long run.

I just wanted to know if any of you have had a similar problem. Maybe the best solution is just to get a new cheaper bike to be safe.

Comment: Can't you just take it with you into your workplace/office? That seemed to be the standard procedure wherever I've seen people commute with road bikes.

Comment: Huh, 1400.- quid for a single speed is quite a price...

Comment: With a single speed bike surely it's easy to take both wheels off and stow it in a cupboard or some out of the way corner.

Comment: Depends on where you are.  Around here you could generally leave the bike unlocked and no one would bother it.  But there are other places it can sprout wings and fly off when you just turn your back, even though you have three locks on it.  The degree of protection necessary depends on the threat.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! You should take the [tour] to find out how things work round here. There are various questions about security here, such as [Locking your bike in public areas](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/937/26152) which you might find helpful; browse the [tag:security] tag for more.

Comment: @gschenk My employers in bike-friendly cities have been quite keen that bikes should not be taken into offices.

Comment: Politely, as the new guy you have a short window to make suggestions at the new job.  If Bike Parking is the one thing you want to fix, then raise it as a suggestion.  Something like "that spare cubical with no windows by the toilets that noone wants to use- may I store my bike in there? "  (ajust as appropriate)

Comment: Get an ugly beater. Something with fender eyelets would be best. Upgrade the critical components you need (pedals, saddle, bearings, etc.) Uglify anything new that sticks out and enjoy the commute. You have plenty of options with a single. An 80's era Japanese steel frame would something to look for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that picking up a second bike is definitely a good approach. Not only does it allow you to not risk your more expensive bike getting stolen, but it allows you to  have a bike more suitable to commuting. You can put fenders and racks on your commuting bike.  Perhaps wider tires if you want something a little more comfortable.  Since you are good with a single speed, this can also be very advantageous on a commuting bike because they are extremely reliable as there are much fewer parts that can have something go wrong with them.

Comment: Indeed, time to expand the bike number i guess. Thank you mate.

Comment: Some more advantages to a second bike: 1. winter salt and sand will not damage your nice bike 2. if, for some reason, in the morning just before leaving to work, you decide there are technical problems with your bike, you get the other one for the day 3. if you get a similar bike, you can spend the second half life of wearable components (drivetrain, tires) on the commuter, and ride shiny parts on the main stead.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kibbee. Would also recommend going fixed for the ultimate in simplicity and weather-proofing as I don't suppose they'll be any shelter for it parking on the street.

Comment: My second bike is actually a fixed gear with fenders.  I still ride my nice touring bike most days as theft doesn't seem to be a big issue where I live. However, on rainy days, or once they start salting the roads for winter, I take my second bike to keep my nice bike in better condition.  It's definitely helped my main bike stay in good condition over the years.

Comment: My main commuter is a Surly Steamroller fixed gear with flat bars (no mud-guards though). It's been a bit of a revelation after riding my racebike or my cyclo-cross bike to work for the past few years - I find fixed to be fantastic for commuting!

Comment: Hi Drew. You recently deleted an answer - I thought it was an ok answer, perhaps you could have improved it after receiving negative comments. You still can. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just take my bike into the office. It would be damaged or stolen pretty quickly if I left it outside even locked. It's just a matter of finding somewhere to park it.

At clients offices I usually leave it with their building security.

I haven't had a bike stolen yet, but I've lost a few things attached to it (people are very light fingered here), so don't leave your bag or anything easily portable with it. I even take off my lights.